# Export MBOX subject and date to CSV using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-csv, mbox

The export format for Gmail is MBOX.  I need create a CSV file with four columns, date, subject, sender, & recipient using python.  First, I am using a script below to get just two columns (date and subject)

My efforts have been unsuccessful using the following script saved as mbox_parser.pl:

```
import mailbox
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open("clean_mail.csv", "wb"))
for message in mailbox.mbox('your_mbox_name'):
    writer.writerow([message['subject'], message['from'], message['date']])
```

I used the command line "python mbox_parser.pl".  Subsequently, the result was a CSV file with 0 bytes.

My skill is very basic.  I started with a script from github [scripts to parse mbox file, convert to csv](https://github.com/gitabites/mboxtocsv)

I appreciate any help given.

4-17-2016 EDIT:

Thank you for removing the python3 tag. I discovered my error. the parameter for mailbox.mbox needed a path as follows:

```
for message in mailbox.mbox('c:\temp\\python\inbox.mbox'):
```

Work well.  However, I did discover that when working for MBOX files created by google.com/takeout, the same emails appeared in multiple MBOX archives. Therefore, I used the following script for each MBOX file to add a unique message-ID and then removed the duplicate lines with a different tool.

```
import mailbox
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open("inbox.csv", "wb"))
for message in mailbox.mbox('c:\\temp\\python\\inbox.mbox'):
writer.writerow([

            message['Date'],
            message['Subject'],
            message['From'],
            message['To'],
            message['Message-Id']
            ]
                    )
```

Thanks to everyone for their interest and help.

Comment: What `mailbox` module are you using and why are you using the extension `.pl` instead of `.py` for your Python scripts?

Comment: What mailbox module are you using? 2.7

Comment: why are you using the extension .pl instead of .py?  I am not. sorry for the typo.